# Confirmation on submit

Tags: javascript, alert, confirmation

I have a form that submits information to a database. How can I make it so that when I click the submit button, I get an alert that asks me if I really want to submit it and when I click "Yes" it continues and if I click "no" it does not submit the information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use JavaScript [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) function.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
```

If the user chooses *Yes*, it will return `true` and the button's default action (submitting the form) will continue as usual. But if the user chooses *No*, it will return `false` and the button's default action will be blocked.

Comment: If confirm return false, the submit will not go ahead, right?