# Confirmation before submit form multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a confirmation before submitting a form but I am using two submit buttons, one for changing account info, which I don't need confirmation, but one for deleting an account, which I do want confirmation for.  I am using php to run my server and would rather ask the conformation before opening the php page.

```
<form id='changeAccountForm' action='processAccountChange.php' method='post'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="action" value="update" id='signUpSubmit'>Submit Changes</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete" class="btn btn-default" id='deleteAccount'>Delete Account</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirmation on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571488/confirmation-on-submit)

Comment: @mickmackusa not duplicate, using several buttons

Comment: any solution about it? not marked answer ? did you tried `onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?");'` ?

Comment: The duplicate offers the appropriate advice.

Answer (score 1):

Add `onclick` event to the button you want confirmation. When return false, the form will not be summited.

```
<button type = "submit" name = "action" value = "delete" class="btn btn- 
default" id = 'deleteAccount' onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?");'>Delete Account</button>
```

Comment: Nice solution, I was about to answer `if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;` but your solution is compact and easy to read and that is appreciated

Comment: And using JQuery dialog box ?